# largest heap ordered subset of nodes in a tree

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

efficient algorithm to find the largest heap ordered subset S of nodes in tree T that has  a heap property. I can think of O(n2)algorithm. can someone plz help me to find O(nlogn)algo.

Comment: Do the nodes need to be a connected tree?

Comment: tree T is connected but subset S may not need to be connected..